# Operational error 2055 while exporting pandas dataframe to MySQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am using `SQLAlchemy` for the first time to export around 6 million records to MySQL. Following is the error I receive:

```
OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\mazin\1-601.xlsx")

database_username = 'root'
database_password = 'aUtO1115'
database_ip       = '127.0.0.1'
database_name     = 'patenting in psis'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                               format(database_username, database_password, 
                                                      database_ip, database_name), pool_recycle=1, pool_timeout=30).connect()

df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='sample', if_exists='replace')
database_connection.close()
```

Note: I do not get the error if I export around 100 records. After referring to similar posts, I have added the `pool_recycle` and `pool_timeout` parameters but the error still persists.

Comment: If you're inserting 6 million rows, you for sure exceed timeout of 30 seconds. Have you tried to input chunks instead all at once. `to_sql` has optional parameter `chunksize` that you can use.

Comment: @PerunSS - I got the same error when I used a timeout of 57600 seconds. Also, when I use the chunksize parameter, it gives me Programming Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%(Maintenance Status (US))s, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Ma' at line 1

Comment: @PerunSS - The use of the chunksize parameter and setting appropriate values for pool_recycle and pool_timeout made the code work. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that you're trying to import 6 million rows as one chunk. And it is taking time. With your current config, `pool_recycle` is set to 1 second, meaning connection will close after 1 second, and that for sure is not enough time to insert 6 mill rows. My suggestion is next:

```
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(
        database_username, 
        database_password,
        database_ip, database_name
    ), pool_recycle=3600, pool_size=5).connect()
df.to_sql(
    con=database_connection, 
    name='sample', 
    if_exists='replace',
    chunksize=1000
)
```

This will set pool of 5 connections with recycle time of 1 hour. And second line will insert 1000 at a time (instead of all the rows at once). You can experiment with values to achieve best performance.

Comment: This was super useful